# how to use here-strings in a Dockerfile?

Tags: linux, bash, docker, dockerfile, containers

I am trying to install mysql-server in debian:buster using Dockerfile as you can see in the following code :

Dockerfile:

```
From debian:buster

RUN apt update

RUN apt install -y gnupg wget lsb-release

RUN wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb

RUN printf "1\n1\n4\n" | dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb

RUN apt update

RUN debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/root-pass password your_password'

RUN debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/re-root-pass password your_password'

RUN apt-get -y install mysql-server

CMD bash
```

and I wanted to install it non-interactively (without being asked any configuration questions), so I used debconf command, to do that but It doesn't work when I try to run it with RUN in the Dockerfile and this error occurs during the build :

[image]

So is it possible to use here-strings in a Dockerfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need here-strings. You are already using the alternative earlier in your Dockerfile.

```
RUN printf '%s\n' 'mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/root-pass password your_password' | debconf-set-selections
RUN printf '%s\n' 'mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/re-root-pass password your_password' | debconf-set-selections
```

`echo` doesn't behave consistently across otherwise POSIX-compliant implementations; prefer `printf` instead.

Comment: It works perfectly, but now I have another problem that I didn't have when I want to start mysql with `service mysql start` it won't work as you can see in this image https://i.imgur.com/xkyleca.png

Comment: Please don't ask unrelated follow-up questions in a comment. Start a new question.

Comment: ok sir, just because it was working before when I was doing it manually without dockerfile  and now with your solution it doesn't work any more.